# How to style nested component in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have a component inside a component and I don't know how to style it in my css file. I tried a lot of different methods but nothing works.

So it looks like this:

outter.component.html

```
<div><my-custom-component></my-custom-component></div>
```

my-custom-component.component.html

and from outter.component.scss 
I want to add

```
i{
  color: red;
}
```

I want to apply styles to my nested component. I tried :host >>> i {}, ::shadow and different appraoches with them but nothing worked.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but it feels like something you should avoid if possible.

Comment: How to avoid it if we want to change style of component in one place?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p7shy8 - check this repo, in the app.component.scss you will see on how to manipulate a component from outside.. But as people already said.. normally you should not style it too much from outside

Comment: So for example, adding parameter to the component and changing it where we use it is better idea?

Comment: @EnesYalçın this is not the same. The OP is not asking to style the component element but rather a child of the component element. e.g. `my-custom-component` has an `i` element which he wants to style.

Comment: @Flink the answer from this worked. And Yeah it is duplicate because it is what I wanted to know. But I couldn't find that question. Thank You!

Comment: @Kaspazza no problem!

Comment: @Mathyn Uh got things mixed up thanks for letting me know (y)